# ExtJS 6.2 Cartesian Chart: Custom rendering of crosshair interaction?

Tags: javascript, extjs6.2

I have a ExtJS 6.2 Cartesian Chart that has a custom renderer function for displaying timestamps on the xAxis, and numbers on the yAxis. The renderer is converting the store.timestamp from ISO 8660 format to UTC, so the axis values show  in UTC (GMT) time. However, when the crosshair interaction is activated via mouse-down, the box on the xAxis still shows local time and is different from the axis values by the GMT offset (in my case -0400).

Is there a way to apply a custom renderer function to modify what is shown in the crosshair tooltip box? Aside from converting the date format at the store level?

Comment: Hey vonnor. Could you post your code so we can see what you're trying?

Comment: I was tasked with getting the crosshair interaction (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.chart.interactions.Crosshair.html) on an existing chart to show the correct timestamps.

Comment: Unfortunately the actual code is on a higher level network and not available to copy here. I was trying to look at the ExtJS api to see if it's even possible without modifying-in-place the data store that feeds the chart.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.chart.axis.Axis.html#cfg-renderer

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.chart.interactions.Crosshair.html